# How to use an alias on server with JSch?

Tags: java, linux, bash, alias, jsch

I want to use an alias in my JSch-connection. I successfully built a connection to the Linux-Server.

In the Linux-Server there's an alias for `ls -l` called `ll`. 
When I type the alias in PuTTY I have no problems, but through JSch I get the following Error:

```
bash: ll: command not found
```

What the hell is wrong here? Here's a preview of my code:

```
package test;

import java.io.InputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UIKeyboardInteractive;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo;

public class SSHConnection {
    private static String host = "", username = "", password = "";
    private static int port = 22;
    private static String[] commands = {"ll /", "df -h"};

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);

            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo() {
                public void showMessage(String message) {}
                public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            session.setUserInfo(ui);
            session.connect();

            for (String command : commands) {
                Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");  // runs commands 
                ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);    // setting command

                channel.setInputStream(null);
                ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);   // Error input
                InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

                channel.connect();

                byte[] temp = new byte[1024]; //temporary savings

                System.out.println("Hostname:\t" + host + "\nCommand:\t" + 
                command + "\n\nResult:\n----------");

                while (true) {
                    // reads while the inputStream contains strings
                    while (in.available() > 0) {
                        int i = in.read(temp, 0, temp.length);
                        if (i < 0) break;
                        System.out.print(new String(temp, 0, i));
                    }
                    if (channel.isClosed()) {
                        if (in.available() > 0) continue;
                        if (channel.getExitStatus() != 0) { // Error-Check
                            System.out.println("----------\nExit-status: " + 
                            channel.getExitStatus() + "\n\n");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("\n\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    // pauses the code for 1 s
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
                channel.disconnect();
                in.close();
            }

            session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static abstract class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {
        public String getPassword() { return null; }
        public boolean promptYesNo(String str) { return false; }
        public String getPassphrase() { return null; }
        public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) { return false; }
        public boolean promptPassword(String message) { return false; }
        public void showMessage() { }
        public String [] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                                   String name,
                                                   String instruction,
                                                   String[] prompt,
                                                   boolean[] echo) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

**EDIT :**
I forgot to tell you, that I have no problems with the login and the command `df -h`.

Comment: Is user/pass used in PUTTY and JSch same?

Comment: Of course is the login the same. I have no problems with login and with the command df -h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is really to not use aliases at all; they are intended as a convenience for interactive use.  If you have a complex alias which you would like to use noninteractively, convert it to a regular shell script, save the file in your `$PATH`, and mark it as executable.  Or convert it to a function.  Even for interactive use, functions are actually superior to aliases, and work in noninteractive shells, too.

Having said that, you can always wing it.  The command you execute could be, for example,

```
 private static String[] commands = {"bash -O expand_aliases -c 'll /'", "df -h"};
```

You may need to smuggle a newline into that command line if you need to explicitly `source` the alias definition before you can use it; there is a caveat in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) about this. (Do read all of it, and especially the last sentence.)

Of course, for something this simple, the proper solution is to just run the standard command `ls -l` and forget about the alias.  It's better for portability, too; while many sites have this alias, it's by no means guaranteed to exist.  (Personally, the first thing I do when I set up an account is remove these "de facto standard" aliases.)

Comment: I solved the problem without using the aliases. Thank you very much for your help and the detailed informations!

Answer (score 0):

`ll` alias usually be defined in `~/.bashrc` file. when you login using a shell this `.bashrc` run and set the alias.

one way is to run it after login by JSch:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

if you can not find the `ll` definition in `~/.bashrc` (either in `etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login and ~/.profile`), use the `alias` command in PUTTY and write result to a script-file. then after JSch login run that script.

```
$ alias 
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

$alias > my-script
$chmod +x my-script
```

Comment: Still have problems. I run the command `. .bashrc` and it works, but the alias `ll` won't even start. For the alias `ll` still getting the errorcode 127.

Comment: can you see the `~/.bashrc` content and find `ll` definition in it?

Comment: i mean in  PUTTY: `cat ~/.bashrc`

Comment: `# User specific aliases and functions` is empty. But I was told that the command is reachable. What shall I do? Actually I tested the alias `ll` and works in PuTTY.

Comment: other file that may contain the `ll` definition is `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile`

Comment: Can't find them in your given paths. Where shall I search for them and how? Actually do I need starting the alias-file when the server is always switched on? I actually wants to use my alias with JSch not with PuTTY, because my alias works in PuTTY but not in JSch.

Comment: you must find where the alias is defined. I mentioned some of possible files, but it may be in other file...

Comment: one way is to using `alais` command in putty and save the result in a script-file and run the file after JSch login.

Comment: Still have Problems after running `. myscript`. What shall I do now? Can I modify JSch so that I can run my commands without checking if it is bash or not?